# List of objects of type which I don't yet know C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with designing my function so that it can act differently for different types. My function is used to create List of objects with different types, so it wouldn't be a problem to create several similar functions, but if it's possible I'd like to avoid it to make my code a bit shorter:

```
static const int FIRST_TYPE = 0;
static const int SECOND_TYPE = 1;
static const int THIRD_TYPE = 2;
```

I use those `int`s as an argument for the function:

```
public void foo(int type)
{
    List<TypeIDontYetKnow> deserialized; 
    switch (type)
    {
        case FIRST_TYPE:
            deserialized = new List<A>();
            break;
        case SECOND_TYPE:
            deserialized = new List<B>();
            break;
        case THIRD_TYPE:
            deserialized = new List<C>();
            break;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: If you _are_ going for this solution, use an `Enum` instead of separate `const` values.

Comment: How do you then *use* `deserialized`? I presume it must be something later in this same function, since its a local and it's a `void` method.

Comment: By the way, in C# you use PascalCase for `const` members and the must not have a `static` modifier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a generic method

```
public void foo<T>()
{
    List<T> deserialized = new List<T>();
}
```

Comment: From looking at the code above this isn't going to be enough. The OP is using an `int` (which really should be an `enum`) to determine which sort of list to instantiate. Really what they are after is a factory method.

Comment: thats what I was going to suggest +1, this code is equivalent to the example. Except it takes a type parameter instead of a loose `int`.

Comment: @James I am suspecting it is harding coding the types. Let's see if the OP will find this useful, or add some more information.

Comment: Yes @MBen It's exactly what I was looking for. Those ints were indeed hard coded types. Thank you! I will mark this as an answer soon. :)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do it by using the non-generic `IList` for `deserialized`, since `List<T>` implements it:

```
IList deserialized;
```

You *shouldn't* do that, however. Further details on what you're trying to achieve might help us to suggest you a better solution:

- Firstly there is [MBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212286/17713) with a **generic method**.
- If `A`, `B` and `C` have a **mutual subclass**, it might be possible not to distinguish
  between the types at compile time but use a `List<ABCBase>` in the
  first place.